# How to keep specific rows of a matrix based on their second element

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Suppose I have the following list:

```
  list1 = {{a, 1, c, v, f}, {m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {k, 3, g, 
  f, a}, {l, 2, h, j, k}, {b, 1, n, m, d}}
```

I need to extract list2 from list1 in which I only keep the rows that their second element is the number "2" (in general number 2 can be a specific letter or any number)

```
 list2 = {{m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {l, 2, h, j, k}}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Cases[{_, 2, ___}] @ list1
```

> ```
> {{m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {l, 2, h, j, k}}
> ```

Also

```
Select[#[[2]] == 2 &] @ list1
```

> ```
> {{m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {l, 2, h, j, k}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {{a, 1, c, v, f}, {m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g},
      {k, 3, g, f, a}, {l, 2, h, j, k}, {b, 1, n, m, d}};

l2 = {{m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {l, 2, h, j, k}};
```

Another way using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[l1, {s : {_, 2, __}} :> s] === l2

(*True*)
```

Or using `DeleteCases` and `Except`:

```
DeleteCases[list1, {_, Except[2], __}] === l2

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {{a, 1, c, v, f}, {m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {k, 3, g, f, 
    a}, {l, 2, h, j, k}, {b, 1, n, m, d}};

Second = #[[2]] &;

Pick[l1, Second /@ l1, 2]
```

> {{m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {l, 2, h, j, k}}

Answer (score 3):

Just a [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)/[`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) variant:

```
Reap[Sow[#, #[[2]]] & /@ list1, 2][[2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A few more possibilities

```
list = 
{{a, 1, c, v, f}, {m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, 
 {k, 3, g, f, a}, {l, 2, h, j, k}, {b, 1, n, m, d}}
```

Using `Position`

```
p = Position[list[[All, 2]], x_ /; x != 2]
```

{{1}, {4}, {6}}

```
Delete[p] @ list;

MapAt[Nothing, p] @ list;

ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ list;

ReplacePart[p :> Nothing] @ list;
```

Not using `Position`

```
list /. {_?AtomQ, Except[2], __} :> Nothing

Replace[list, {_, Except[2], __} :> Nothing, {1}]

Join @@ SequenceSplit[list, {{_, Except[2], __}}]
```

All return

{{m, 2, s, f, a}, {s, 2, d, f, g}, {l, 2, h, j, k}}